# Forming a differential equation from game

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, game-theory, mathematical-modeling

I was wondering if someone could help me form a differential equation from the following game:

A population consists of two types of diets, fish and veg.
People play a with every other person and the game has the following payoff matrix, indicating the better diet:

```
     |  Fish     | Veg 
------------------------------
Fish | (0,0)     | (1, 1-2c) 
Veg  | (1-2c, 1) | (1-c, 1-c)
```

At the end of a round a person compares to another random person. If the other person's total payoff, $\pi_j$, is larger than the first person's, $\pi_i$, the first person copies the diet of the other person with a probability proportional to differences in performance, $\pi_j - \pi_i$

This is how I think I need to approach it, but I'm new to this and it's all confusing me a little!

**

Let $x$ denote the proportion of fish diets (and $1-x$ denote the proportion of veg diets) and let $\pi$ denote the payoffs per time step:

$\pi_f = (1-x)(1)\\
\pi_d = x(1-2c) + (1-x)(1-c)$

I think change in proportion of fish diets is this, but I'm not sure:

change in fish = -(fish converted to veg) + (veg converted to fish)
$\frac{\delta x}{\delta t} =  -x(1-x)(\pi_f-\pi_v) + x(1-x)(\pi_v+\pi_d)$

If someone could let me know whether I'm doing this correctly and how best to approach this then I would be very grateful.

Thanks